# React testing library fire beforeinstallprompt event

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a React component that listen to `beforeinstallprompt` event to handle PWA app installation. It has an effect hook like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', handleBeforeInstallPromptEvent);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', handleBeforeInstallPromptEvent);
    };
  }, [handleBeforeInstallPromptEvent]);
```

The handler `handleBeforeInstallPromptEvent` do some logic to show a banner asking the user to install the application if it has not already been installed.

To test this behaviour I created this jest test but it is not calling the event handler and consequently not showing the alert.

Am I missing something?

```js
it('should render install app alert if not yet installed', async () => {
    const event = createEvent('beforeinstallprompt', window, {
      userChoice: new Promise((res) => res({ outcome: 'accepted', platform: '' })),
      prompt: () => new Promise((res) => res(undefined)),
    });

    render(<InstallApp />);

    await act(async () => {
      fireEvent(window, event);
    });

    expect(screen.getByText(/Install app!/g)).toBeVisible();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The describe test block has this setup/teardown configuration that is preventing the events to be caught

```js
beforeAll(() => {
  window.addEventListener = jest.fn();
  window.removeEventListener = jest.fn();
});

afterAll(() => {
  (window.addEventListener as any).mockClear();
  (window.removeEventListener as any).mockClear();
});
```